# writing c# program result to csv file

Tags: c#, csv

I have a c# program that compared 2 database tables and uploaded results to another table in database.  I started getting a maxpackets error..which my understanding is that the uploaded results was to large.

My thoughts were to dump results to csv file instead.  I have tried to follow several examples, but my program now just stalls.  What do I have wrong?

```
{
                string filePath = @"C:\users\rena\documents\test.csv";
                string delimiter = ",";

                string[][] output = new string[][]
                {
                    new string[] { "col 1 row 1", "col 2 row 1", "col 3 row 1"},
                    new string[] {"col 1 row 2", "col 2 row 2", "col 3 row 2"}
                };
                int length = output.GetLength(0);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)
                    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(delimiter, output[index]));

                if (!File.Exists(filePath))

                File.WriteAllText (filePath, sb.ToString())

            }
```

THANKS!!

Comment: user-name advertises a commercial site. spam? - looks like not: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253392/is-this-considered-as-spam-or-self-promotion

Comment: does even this example stall? or is this just a minimal version of what stalls? can you make a minimal version that stalls?

Comment: your code looks ok, which error happens?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/). Why can you not “uploaded results to another table”? You get a “maxpackets error”? Show us the error and work on that; fiddling around with CSV files is probably leading you astray.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to write with a Buffered Stream. See if this is more clear:

```
void Main()
{

    string filePath = @"c:\temp\test.csv";
    string delimiter = ",";

    string[][] output = new string[][]
    {
        new string[] { "col 1 row 1", "col 2 row 1", "col 3 row 1"},
        new string[] {"col 1 row 2", "col 2 row 2", "col 3 row 2"}
        //tried with 2k here
    };
    int length = output.GetLength(0);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


    using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(filePath))
    {
        using (BufferedStream bufferedStream = new BufferedStream(fileStream))
        {
            using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(bufferedStream))
            {
                for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)
                    streamWriter.WriteLine(string.Join(delimiter, output[index]));
            }   
        }
    }

    if (!File.Exists(filePath))

    File.WriteAllText (filePath, sb.ToString());

}
```